# Sum by Groups Before and after appear Number in column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of records by id ordered by date ('Date'), which I want to sum up the amounts or, in 2 groups, 1 before any number appears ('Condition'), and another group after the first number,It doesn't matter if a 0 appears after a number, add before any number appears, and add after.
[image]

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  id,
  sum(case when s = 0 then amount else 0 end) as amount_before,
  sum(case when s <> 0 then amount else 0 end) as amount_after  
from (
  select t.*,
    sum(abs(condition)) over(partition by id order by date) as s
  from t
) x
group by id
```

Comment: `count(case when condition <> 0 then 1) over...` or `count(nullif(condition, 0)) over...` seem more obvious ways of doing that window function

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I agree.

Comment: It is not when it is 0 or different from 0, it is when a number appears, after a number appears it does not matter if the next one is 0, it will correspond to the next group